Why is my Azure AD token request returning HTTP 400 consent error for API permissions that have been granted?
I have had a new app registered in my Azure tenant.  It has been configured with the following API permissions, which have been granted admin consent:

If I make a call to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token with the following request body:
grant_type=password
&username={username}
&password={password}
&client_id={clientId}
&scope=user.read

Then I get back an HTTP 200.
However, if I change the scope to files.readwrite, then I get back an HTTP 400 with the following exception:

AADSTS50158: External security challenge not satisfied. User will be
redirected to another page or authentication provider to satisfy
additional authentication challenges.

Presumably this is either seeking MFA, or some additional consent.  However the app will have no UI, so I can't follow a consent process with the user.  We need to be able to pre-consent a small number of users to this app.
I'm running this from our office, which I understand to be a trusted location - so would not expect an MFA challenge (if that's what it is).
I also had my Azure admin add this particular account as a user under Microsoft Entra ID > Enterprise applications > {appName} > Manage > Users and groups, but I'm not sure if that was a necessary step, but I read that it would pre-consent the user to the app.

files.write != Files.ReadWrite

Gah, thank you.  However that creates a new problem.  Editing...

@SirCrispalot the error is because the MFA is enabled for the user

@Rukmini it is true that MFA is enabled, but we don't get MFA challenges in the office - I was told it is a "trusted location".  Why would there be an MFA challenge for one permission but not the other?

ROPC flow do not support for MFA enabled accounts hence you need to switch to authorization code flow to generate token check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth-ropc and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-authentication-flows#constraints-for-ropc

Can I post an answer to generate token using authorization code flow which needs user interaction?

@Rukmini thanks for the info about ROPC.  I think that answers this specific question - you've explained why it returns a 400.  However user interaction is not going to work, this is a back end process that has no UI, but needs access to the user's Drive.  Maybe I should ask a new question.

Sure please post a new question and paste the link here and will post an answer for this

The error "The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '{clientId}' named '{appName}'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource." usually occurs if you are passing wrong scope to generate the token.
To resolve the error, you need to pass scope as Files.ReadWrite
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:clientID
scope:Files.ReadWrite
grant_type:password
username:username
password:password


Note that: ROPC flow do not support MFA enabled accounts, If tried to generate token using ROPC flow then you might get errors. Refer this MsDoc

The error "External security challenge not satisfied. User will be redirected to another page or authentication provider to satisfy additional authentication challenges." usually occurs if you are trying to generate token using ROPC flow.

Hence to resolve the error switch to any other flow to generate the token.
